# How to kill Debian-gdm user processes?

Tags: tails

I am using tails under a VM. I am having problems when the keyboard buffer sharing stops working, and I have looked into the process list and I see two instances of the spice /usr/bin/spice-vdagent. One of them is owned by the currently logged in user amnesia and the other is owned by the the Debian-gdm user. And each user has their own Xserver running.

Is this normal? Why doesn't the Debian-gdm user die after login? Is there a way to make it exit? Logging in as root and killall -u Debian-tor helps, but is there another way?

Comment: Tails support for running inside of a VM is there purely for testing purposes and not intended to be used for normal Tails use since it breaks some of Tails' protections.

Comment: Are two X servers and two users logged in when running on similar PC hardware?

Comment: Yes. That's normal.